# code --verbose not launching VS CODE Showing Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/snap/code'

Tags: 18.04, launcher, snap

When trying to launch VsCode from launcher or terminal it's not launching. On `code --verbose` command it's showing the following error

```
Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/snap/code'
```

Os- Ubuntu 18.04(64bit)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found the answer at a [GitHub thread](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2534#issuecomment-437572537). As j-o-d-o commented:

> Increasing max user watches resolved the issue:
>
> ```
> >> sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384
> ```
>
> Was at 8192 originally